# How To Run Process.start/run unix shell In Flutter Android App?

Tags: android, flutter, shell, dart, unix

I'm trying to make a termux-like app but using flutter,

I just want to run my executable in code dart

code:

```dart
      Directory directory_app = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

      File file = File(path.join(directory_app.path, "cli-test"));
      Future<void> extractCliFromAsset() async {
        var content = await rootBundle.load("assets/cli-test");
        await file.writeAsBytes(content.buffer.asUint8List(), mode: FileMode.writeOnly);
      }

      if (!file.existsSync()) {
        await extractCliFromAsset();
      }

      Process shell = await Process.start(
        file.path,
        [
          "run"
        ],
        workingDirectory: directory_app.path,
        runInShell: false,
      );

      shell.stderr.listen((event) {
        stderr.add(event);
      });

      shell.stdout.listen((event) {
        stdout.add(event);
      });
```

then the error permission denied appears,

I've tried doing chmod to give write storage access,

I've Tried Doing use package

1. https://pub.dev/packages/shell
2. https://pub.dev/packages/process_run

I've Tried Save Executable on storage external,
I've Tried change runInShell, change environment

but nothing works the program I'm running doesn't ask for root at all

how to be able to run unix shell cli programs in android app?

i want my flutter app to run unix shell without root